# Are Bookmarklets Possible in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I was trying to create a bookmarklet in chrome (I was using the console). I got the following error:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js' because
it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 
https://*.facebook.com http://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net 
http://*.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.google-analytics.com *.virtualearth.net
*.google.com 127.0.0.1:* *.spotilocal.com:* 
chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl 'unsafe-inline' 
'unsafe-eval' https://*.akamaihd.net http://*.akamaihd.net".
```

My code was

```
var jQueryLib = document.createElement("script");
jQueryLib.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(jQueryLib);
```

Does this mean creating bookmarklets is no longer possible? What I wanted to do was like a bunch of new comments on my Facebook group and thought a bookmarklet would be a good idea.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

From that error message it is not having an issue with the Bookmarklet itself. The problem is that is that Facebook has declared a list of domains in which scripts may be run from. When you try to inject the jQuery script it sees that the domain (jquery.com in this case) is not on the allowed list and refuses to run it.

As an alternative you could copy and paste the entire jQuery file into console. This would bypass the content restriction. You could also turn the entire jQuery library into a bookmarklet to make it easier to add to a page.

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't aware they could do that.

Answer (score -1):

Yes Javascript Bookmarklets are allowed in Chrome. For example, copy and paste the code below into a bookmark. Change the title to whatever you want, but paste the code below into the URL section. Then press it.

javascript:alert("See, it works");